# Salvar int, mas exibir textos

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou estudando o Cake e estou com uma duvida, tem alguma forma de exibir uma lista, mas salvar um número no BD?

Por exemplo, níveis de permissão:

```
0 - admin
1 - vendas
2 - Edição
3 - Financeiro
```

Em todas as views deve aparecer somente o texto, mas ao salvar salvar o número.

Comment: Acredito que essa parte da documentação possa te ajudar melhor, https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Então, será que tem como fazer isso na model, facilitando a manutenção depois?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a Entidade pra isso, através de um campo virtual.
Deixe seu campo (que é salvo no banco) como hidden, e cria um novo campo (com outro nome) como virtual.

Dai, cria um setter que recebe o valor em string, transforma em número e salva o dado no campo do banco, e um getter pega o número do banco e retorna a respectiva string.

Seria algo assim:

```
class User extends Entity
{
    protected $_hidden = ['permissoes'];
    protected $_virtual = ['cargo'];

    protected function _getCargo()
    {
        $dicionario = [
            0 => 'admin', 
            1 => 'vendas', 
            2 => 'Edição',
            3 => 'Financeiro'
        ];
        return $dicionario[$this->_properties['permissoes']];
    }
    protected function _setCargo($cargo)
    {
        $dicionario = [
            'admin' => 0, 
            'vendas' => 1, 
            'Edição' => 2,
            'Financeiro' => 3
        ];
        return $dicionario[$cargo];
    }
}
```

Comment: Só lembra de verificar ali na variavel $dicionario se o indice existe, se não, pode dar o erro undefiend index